# How to update_all (with a where clause) for many embedded documents with Mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have an Item class and a Comment class. Items have many embedded comments.

Comments also store a user's username, so if a user changes their username, I want to update all of their comments.

I want to do something like this (obviously it doesn't work):

```
Item.where('comments.username' => 'elvis33').update_all('comments.username' => 'elvis')
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[$ positional operator](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-The%24positionaloperator) has the limitation `only applies to the first matched item in the query`. There is a open issue in [Jira](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1243) regarding the issue (Vote it if you really need the feature)

So that leaves us no choice other than retrieving the comments collection and update all comments by looping it.

```
items = Item.only(:comments).where('comments.username' => 'elvis33')
items.each do |item|
    item.comments.select {|com| com.username == 'elvis33'}.each do |comment|
       comment.username = 'elvis'
    end
item.save
end
```

The above code updates each item once with all modified comment user names. I haven't tested the code.

Comment: Thanks for the info and code RameshVel. I got it working with your code, except for the `.only(:comments)` clause; I wonder if that's because comments are nested documents. Anyway, your answer seems like the best way to do it, until they enhance the $ positional operator.

Answer (score 0):

Since username is actually part of an document of an embedded array, you have to use the [positional operator](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-The%24positionaloperator) like this:

Item.where('comments.username' => 'elvis33').update_all('comments.$.username' => 'elvis')

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this won't work. From the documentation: Currently the $ operator only applies to the **first** matched item in the query.